# PostgreSQL, GROUP BY and Window function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got the following query in `PostgreSQL` which works showing records:

```
'SELECT TO_CHAR(date_trunc(\'hour\', time::timestamp), \'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS\') AS time_from,
        TO_CHAR(date_trunc(\'hour\', time::timestamp) + interval \'1 hour\', \'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS\') AS time_to,
        SUM(km) AS km
 FROM cars 
 GROUP BY date_trunc(\'hour\', time::timestamp) LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 50'
```

I would like to add `SUM(km) OVER() as km_total` for getting the total amount of `km` as I have `limit` and `offset` in my query.

But then I get the error:

```
error: column "cars.km" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

But I'm not allowed to add it to my `GROUP BY`, this gives me the following error:

```
error: window functions are not allowed in GROUP BY
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want:

```
   SUM(SUM(km)) OVER () AS total_km
```

The nesting of the `SUM()` looks strange at first.  The inner `SUM(km)` is the aggregation function.  The outer `SUM()` is the window function.